# Do posts use a revision system?

Tags: support, faq, editing

I made some too aggressive edits to a certain question, and the author has asked me to restore the text. I thought there was a revisions system where I could pick the old text, but I can't seem to find it.

I dug up the original text under my "activities" tab, so I can work the problem out from there, but

- Is there a revisions system for content?
- Under what conditions can it be accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a post has been edited after it has been created, the post shows the user who edited the question. The timestamp shown after "edited" is a link to the revision page, which shows all the revisions for that post.

[image: screenshot]

It's not considered a new revision if the edit has been done in the 5-minute grace period; this means that if the user creates a post, and then edit it before 5 minutes are passed, the "edited" link will not appear.

In the revision page, you rollback a previous version by clicking on the "rollback" link shown for the revision you want to restore.

[image: screenshot]

The "rollback" link is visible to the users who can edit the post, which means:

- to the user who created the post, independently from the reputation that user has
- to any user with the privilege of editing any post, which is a privilege gained when the user's reputation is at least 2000

When there is a pending suggested edit, you are probably not allowed to rollback a previous revision, without first approving the suggested edit; as I have never been in that situation, I cannot say it's exactly what happens.